# How to change icon color when i clicked on button?

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I change the color of icon on click?

Is using the `ngClass` is the best option?

What I have done so far is assign a class to my icon.

```html
<ion-card>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
                <ion-icon name="eye" #name [ngClass]="{
                'isActive' : isActive}" (click)="activeCheck(name)">
                </ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-card>
```

*.ts file*

```js
export class NewsPage implements OnInit {
    isActive: boolean = false;

    activeCheck(name) {
        console.log(name);
        this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some styles for activated class and following does the job. ngClass adding the class dynamically based on value of isActive variable. You can use isActive value change for (click) instead of using a function call.

```
<ion-icon name="eye" #name [ngClass]="isActive ? 'activated' : ''" (click)="isActive = !isActive">
</ion-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a function for this. You can simply toggle the value of `isActive` property in the template.

Also, make the `(click)` event handler on the `button` instead of the `ion-icon`.

And, use `[class.isActive]="isActive"` for a shorter syntax.

Here's the code:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col>
    <button 
      ion-button 
      icon-left 
      clear 
      small 
      (click)="isActive = !isActive">
      <ion-icon 
        name="eye" 
        #name 
        [class.isActive]="isActive">
      </ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/profile-picture-change-shared-service?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) for your ref.

Comment: But I have three buttons and each button contains an icon, I want when you click on any one their color changes only and others do not happen to them

Comment: I've updated the stackblitz to cater to that scenario. If you have different icons for each button as well, you can add the icon type to the `buttonsState` array in the Component Class and then take it from there in the template.